# Decide whether the sum is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{n!}(\frac{n}{e})^n$$

I have tried both ratio test and root test, both results in $1$, which cannot give any conclusion. Also the series itself goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity and the series is not monotonic increasing.

I ran out of methods... I think the only way left is to solve by comparison test but I have no idea what will be the lower bound...

Please help...

Comment: Do you know *Stirling's formula*?

Comment: @Bernard No.. I haven't learned it before...

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) would allow you to show that each summand is $\ge 0.3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (for all sufficiently large $n$), at which point you can apply a comparison test.

Comment: @SixTwelfthsPi: Well it simply says that $n!$ is asymptotically equivalent to $ \sqrt{2\pi n}\biggl( \dfrac n{\mathrm e}\biggr)^n$, which makes the answer obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $n\geq 1$. Observe that
\begin{align*}
\log n! & = \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\log k}  = \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {\log k\, dt} }  \le \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {\log t\, dt} } \\ & = \log n + \int_1^n {\log t \, dt} 
 = \log n + n\log n - n + 1.
\end{align*}
Taking the exponential of both sides of the inequality gives
$$
n! \le n\left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n e \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{e}\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{{n!}}\left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n .
$$
Consequently,
$$
\frac{1}{e}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}}  \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}\left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n } ,
$$
but the series on the left-hand side is the divergent harmonic series, i.e., the series in question must diverge too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

As this is a series with positive terms, use Stirling's asymptotic equivalent for $n!$.

Comment: Could you please write down the steps if possible?